# Shower valve issue?

Tags: shower, valve, delta

Is this a problem (see picture)? I’ve had hot water issues in the house since this was installed and am feeling as though the valve is mixing and sending hot water into the cold pipe but I don’t know much about it. Any experienced opinions would be appreciated. Thanks.

[image]

Comment: What do you mean by "hot water issues'? What symptoms are you seeing? The pics raise some interesting questions but more details about your situation would help to diagnose what might be going on so someone here can help you.

Comment: The pic in question is part of a master bath remodel. I’ve been using another shower in the house during this process. It was previously very hot. 

Since this new valve install, it only gets luke warm even after I turned the hot water stop as high as it goes (essentially letting the water get even hotter than before.) The same is true for another shower in the house as well; it doesn’t get as hot as it did before this remodel project and more specifically, this valve install. Thanks.

Comment: if you think this valve is the problem. disconnect it and see if that helps.

Comment: where does the copper go to? where does the pex go to?

Comment: I don’t have the equipment to cap/disconnect the pex to verify it’s the problem.      The 2 outside copper lines extend up about 12” and are capped off. The center copper line is the output for the shower head. The pex lines are hot and cold lines coming in.

Comment: With the water turned off, you should be able to pull the valve out of the valve body and put in the plug that came with the valve body.  When you have the plug installed and the valve body capped, turn on the water and see if the problem persists.  If it does, then there is something wrong with your valve body.  If it does not, then the valve installation was the problem.  Re-install the valve, carefully following the instructions that came with it.  Water should not be able to pass through the valve from hot to cold or vice-versa.